# Can I group objects based on their transform values?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to do a very simple code in Maya python which will group my objects based on their value. The code that I have so far should be working but it doesn't. Can someone please help me see what I'm missing in this code and why isn't it running?

```
mesh= []
          
for obj in mesh:     
    Sattr = cmds.getAttr (mesh+'.ty') 
if Sattr > 5:        
    cmds.group (name='Big')
```

Comment: Can you please give some examples with input and expected output? Based on your code (without examples), I can see there is an uninitialised error for `Sattr`.

Comment: You are iterating over an empty array. And you try to get the ty attribute from an array but it should be **cmds.getAttr(obj+ ".ty")**.

Answer (score 0):

```
meshes = cmds.ls(sl=True) # define the selection to be parsed
to_group = []         
for obj in mesh:     
    Sattr = cmds.getAttr (obj+'.ty')  # you want to parse obj and not mesh
    if Sattr > 5:
         to_group.append(obj) # you want your if to be within your loop
cmds.group(to_group, name='Big') # if you don't provide what you want to group as argument, it will group your selection. So you have two options. Create an empty group and then parent object to it or group every mesh at once
```